# Definitive best way to add properties/methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods, properties

I got tired of writing long object property/method expressions *like the example below*. Adding every property one by one seemed like such a waist of keystrokes.

```
var foo = function(object){
      object.foo = "foo";
      object.function = function(){};
      return object; 

}
```

I got so frustrated with it, I thought there had to be a better way. After a bit of thought the best thing I could come up with was a addProperties loop function, like so.

```
var addProperties = function(properties, subject){
    subject = subject ? subject : {};

    for(propertie in properties){
        if(properties.hasOwnProperty(propertie) && !subject[propertie]){
            subject[propertie] = properties[propertie]
        }
    }
    return subject;
}
```

This does make the code a bit more concise :

```
var foo = function(object){
    return addProperties({foo : "foo", function : function(){}}, object); 
}
```

BUT I AM NOT SATISFIED!!

So I am turning to you, the great people of stack overflow : **what is the definitive best way to add properties/methods?** (In your personal opinions)

Answer (score 1):

As it's tagged with jQuery

```
var foo = function(obj){
    return $.extend(obj, {
       foo      : "foo",
       function : function(){}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps...

```
var foo = {
    bar: 'bar',
    thatNamedFunction: function(){
        console.log('That named function of foo');
    },
    thatFunctionThatReturnsBar: function() {
        console.log('Returning bar');
        return this.bar;
    },
    thatFunctionThatManipulatesBar: function(newValue) {
        console.log('Bar will now be the newValue')
        this.bar = newValue;
    }
}
```